# Hibernate Batch Save Nested Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

I have the below class structure:

```
class A{
    int id;
    List<B> blist;
    List<C> clist;
    List<D> dlist;
}
```

I get a json as an input which is mapped to object **A** by a mapper. Now, i have object **A** which has the list of **B,C and D** objects. I want to use batching to save the insert time taken. I went through the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) which describes the solution if I want to save multiple parent objects. How would I use the batching capability in my case which has nested list of objects of multiple type.

I have enabled batch inserts using

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
```

This by itself doesnt give me any batching unless I clear and flush the session. Any suggestions on how do I go about with this?

Comment: How do you know it isn't batching the inserts?  Hibernate doesn't automatically send SQL statements to the database until you `flush` or `commit` the transaction, at which point if multiple inserts can be sent in a batch, they will be.

Comment: @Naros I'm guessing it's not batching because it is taking 30 seconds to insert about 500 records

Comment: What identifier generation strategy are you using?

Comment: It is auto increment in dB table and in entity class it is strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `IDENTITY` strategy.

Whenever you save a new entity, Hibernate will place it into the Session's 1LC; however, in order to do that the identifier must be known.  The problem with `IDENTITY` strategy is that Hibernate must actually perform the insert to determine the identifier value.

In the end, batch insert capabilities are disabled.

You should either try to load your data using business key values that are known up front or worse case use `SEQUENCE` generation type with a sequence optimizer to minimize the database hit.  This will allow batch inserts to work.

#### UPDATE

For situations where you have no business key that defines the uniqueness for a row and your database doesn't have `SEQUENCE` support, you could manage the identifiers yourself.  You can either elect to do this using a custom identifier generator or just doing this in your loop as code.

The caveat here is that *this solution is **not** thread-safe*.  You should guarantee that at no point would you ever be running this logic in two threads simultaneously, which is typically not something one does anyway with bulk data loads.

1. Define a variable to store your identifier in.  We will need to initialize this variable based on the existing max value of the identifier in the database.  If no rows in the database exist, we likely will want to initialize it as 1.

   ```
   Long value = ... // createQuery ( "SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourEntity" )
   value = ( value == null ? 1L : value + 1);
   ```
2. The next step is to change the `@Id` annotated field.  It should not be marked as `@GeneratedValue` since we're going to allow the application to provide the value.
3. For each row you're going to insert, simply call your `#setId( value )` method with the value variable generated from step 1.
4. Increment your `value` variable by 1.

Comment: ok that's sounds alright. Any pseudo code on how do I actually use the solutions suggested?

Comment: It's pretty clear, change your `@GeneratedValue` to use `(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` being one of them or determine if you have a unique value in the loaded rows from your input source and if so, mark that field as `@Id` instead without a `@GeneratedValue`.

Comment: I'm using MySQL and that doesn't seem to have a Sequence sadly :/

Comment: I added some logic I used to improve data imports on SQL Server when I wanted to optimize out any SEQUENCE/IDENTITY overhead.  It has some caveats but it works so long as you can work without the constraints I outlined.

Comment: I see "DEBUG o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - Reusing batch statement" and "Executing batch size: 50" in my logs. Does that mean the batching is working ? I dont see any improvement in the insertion duration though !